Node 16 Installation Warnings keep on repeating without stopping. How to solve the installation issues?
I had Node 16 installed initially, and I wanted to install Node 20 to use with a specific module of a software. So I cleaned npm caches and then installed the Node 20. Afterwards I wanted to use Node 16 again because I'm working with an ERPNext 14 system which requires Node 14 - 16, and higher versions are not supported. So now I was trying to install Node 16 again, but now I keep on getting warning stating "g++: warning: switch ‘-msign-return-address=all’ is no longer supported". The warning message is quite large. I need a work around for this, to install Node 16.
Below is the complete warnings,
ransike@ransikevm:~$ nvm install v16.20.2
Downloading and installing node v16.20.2...
Local cache found: ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/bin/node-v16.20.2-linux-arm64/node-v16.20.2-linux-arm64.tar.xz
Checksums match! Using existing downloaded archive ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/bin/node-v16.20.2-linux-arm64/node-v16.20.2-linux-arm64.tar.xz
mv: cannot move '/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v16.20.2-linux-arm64/files/bin' to '/home/ransike/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move '/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v16.20.2-linux-arm64/files/include' to '/home/ransike/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/include': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move '/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v16.20.2-linux-arm64/files/lib' to '/home/ransike/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move '/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v16.20.2-linux-arm64/files/share' to '/home/ransike/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/share': Directory not empty
Binary download failed, trying source.
Local cache found: ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/node-v16.20.2.tar.xz
Checksums match! Using existing downloaded archive ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/node-v16.20.2.tar.xz
$>./configure --prefix=/home/ransike/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2 <
Node.js configure: Found Python 3.10.12...
INFO: configure completed successfully
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=0
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/lib.host:/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/lib.target:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd ../tools/icu; mkdir -p /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen; "/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/icupkg" -tl ../../deps/icu-tmp/icudt71l.dat "/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/icudt71l.dat"
  touch 1390b7777634193bfa164966292fdaf0369a6e46.intermediate
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/lib.host:/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/lib.target:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd ../tools/v8_gypfiles; mkdir -p /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated/src/ic /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated/src/wasm /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated/test/torque /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated/src/objects /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated/src/debug /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated/src/builtins /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated/third_party/v8/builtins; "/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/torque" -o "/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated" -v8-root ../../deps/v8 src/builtins/aggregate-error.tq src/builtins/array-at.tq src/builtins/array-concat.tq src/builtins/array-copywithin.tq src/builtins/array-every.tq src/builtins/array-filter.tq src/builtins/array-find.tq src/builtins/array-findindex.tq src/builtins/array-findlast.tq src/builtins/array-findlastindex.tq src/builtins/array-foreach.tq src/builtins/array-from.tq src/builtins/array-isarray.tq src/builtins/array-join.tq src/builtins/array-lastindexof.tq src/builtins/array-map.tq src/builtins/array-of.tq src/builtins/array-reduce-right.tq src/builtins/array-reduce.tq src/builtins/array-reverse.tq src/builtins/array-shift.tq src/builtins/array-slice.tq src/builtins/array-some.tq src/builtins/array-splice.tq src/builtins/array-unshift.tq src/builtins/array.tq src/builtins/arraybuffer.tq src/builtins/base.tq src/builtins/boolean.tq src/builtins/builtins-bigint.tq src/builtins/builtins-string.tq src/builtins/cast.tq src/builtins/collections.tq src/builtins/constructor.tq src/builtins/conversion.tq src/builtins/convert.tq src/builtins/console.tq src/builtins/data-view.tq src/builtins/finalization-registry.tq src/builtins/frames.tq src/builtins/frame-arguments.tq src/builtins/function.tq src/builtins/growable-fixed-array.tq src/builtins/ic-callable.tq src/builtins/ic-dynamic-check-maps.tq src/builtins/ic.tq src/builtins/internal-coverage.tq src/builtins/internal.tq src/builtins/iterator.tq src/builtins/math.tq src/builtins/number.tq src/builtins/object-fromentries.tq src/builtins/object.tq src/builtins/promise-abstract-operations.tq src/builtins/promise-all.tq src/builtins/promise-all-element-closure.tq src/builtins/promise-any.tq src/builtins/promise-constructor.tq src/builtins/promise-finally.tq src/builtins/promise-misc.tq src/builtins/promise-race.tq src/builtins/promise-reaction-job.tq src/builtins/promise-resolve.tq src/builtins/promise-then.tq src/builtins/promise-jobs.tq src/builtins/proxy-constructor.tq src/builtins/proxy-delete-property.tq src/builtins/proxy-get-property.tq src/builtins/proxy-get-prototype-of.tq src/builtins/proxy-has-property.tq src/builtins/proxy-is-extensible.tq src/builtins/proxy-prevent-extensions.tq src/builtins/proxy-revocable.tq src/builtins/proxy-revoke.tq src/builtins/proxy-set-property.tq src/builtins/proxy-set-prototype-of.tq src/builtins/proxy.tq src/builtins/reflect.tq src/builtins/regexp-exec.tq src/builtins/regexp-match-all.tq src/builtins/regexp-match.tq src/builtins/regexp-replace.tq src/builtins/regexp-search.tq src/builtins/regexp-source.tq src/builtins/regexp-split.tq src/builtins/regexp-test.tq src/builtins/regexp.tq src/builtins/string-at.tq src/builtins/string-endswith.tq src/builtins/string-html.tq src/builtins/string-includes.tq src/builtins/string-indexof.tq src/builtins/string-iterator.tq src/builtins/string-match-search.tq src/builtins/string-pad.tq src/builtins/string-repeat.tq src/builtins/string-replaceall.tq src/builtins/string-slice.tq src/builtins/string-startswith.tq src/builtins/string-substr.tq src/builtins/string-substring.tq src/builtins/string-trim.tq src/builtins/symbol.tq src/builtins/torque-internal.tq src/builtins/typed-array-at.tq src/builtins/typed-array-createtypedarray.tq src/builtins/typed-array-every.tq src/builtins/typed-array-entries.tq src/builtins/typed-array-filter.tq src/builtins/typed-array-find.tq src/builtins/typed-array-findindex.tq src/builtins/typed-array-findlast.tq src/builtins/typed-array-findlastindex.tq src/builtins/typed-array-foreach.tq src/builtins/typed-array-from.tq src/builtins/typed-array-keys.tq src/builtins/typed-array-of.tq src/builtins/typed-array-reduce.tq src/builtins/typed-array-reduceright.tq src/builtins/typed-array-set.tq src/builtins/typed-array-slice.tq src/builtins/typed-array-some.tq src/builtins/typed-array-sort.tq src/builtins/typed-array-subarray.tq src/builtins/typed-array-values.tq src/builtins/typed-array.tq src/builtins/weak-ref.tq src/ic/handler-configuration.tq src/objects/allocation-site.tq src/objects/api-callbacks.tq src/objects/arguments.tq src/objects/bigint.tq src/objects/cell.tq src/objects/code.tq src/objects/contexts.tq src/objects/data-handler.tq src/objects/debug-objects.tq src/objects/descriptor-array.tq src/objects/embedder-data-array.tq src/objects/feedback-cell.tq src/objects/feedback-vector.tq src/objects/fixed-array.tq src/objects/foreign.tq src/objects/free-space.tq src/objects/heap-number.tq src/objects/heap-object.tq src/objects/js-array-buffer.tq src/objects/js-array.tq src/objects/js-collection-iterator.tq src/objects/js-collection.tq src/objects/js-function.tq src/objects/js-generator.tq src/objects/js-objects.tq src/objects/js-promise.tq src/objects/js-proxy.tq src/objects/js-regexp-string-iterator.tq src/objects/js-regexp.tq src/objects/js-weak-refs.tq src/objects/literal-objects.tq src/objects/map.tq src/objects/megadom-handler.tq src/objects/microtask.tq src/objects/module.tq src/objects/name.tq src/objects/oddball.tq src/objects/ordered-hash-table.tq src/objects/primitive-heap-object.tq src/objects/promise.tq src/objects/property-array.tq src/objects/property-cell.tq src/objects/property-descriptor-object.tq src/objects/prototype-info.tq src/objects/regexp-match-info.tq src/objects/scope-info.tq src/objects/script.tq src/objects/shared-function-info.tq src/objects/source-text-module.tq src/objects/stack-frame-info.tq src/objects/string.tq src/objects/struct.tq src/objects/swiss-hash-table-helpers.tq src/objects/swiss-name-dictionary.tq src/objects/synthetic-module.tq src/objects/template-objects.tq src/objects/templates.tq src/objects/torque-defined-classes.tq test/torque/test-torque.tq third_party/v8/builtins/array-sort.tq src/objects/intl-objects.tq src/objects/js-break-iterator.tq src/objects/js-collator.tq src/objects/js-date-time-format.tq src/objects/js-display-names.tq src/objects/js-list-format.tq src/objects/js-locale.tq src/objects/js-number-format.tq src/objects/js-plural-rules.tq src/objects/js-relative-time-format.tq src/objects/js-segment-iterator.tq src/objects/js-segmenter.tq src/objects/js-segments.tq src/builtins/wasm.tq src/debug/debug-wasm-objects.tq src/wasm/wasm-objects.tq
  touch c9aad91afa17ea85ec551d35b8e7bd864c98eb39.intermediate
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/lib.host:/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/lib.target:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd ../tools/v8_gypfiles; mkdir -p /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/inspector-generated-output-root/src/inspector/protocol /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/inspector-generated-output-root/include/inspector; /usr/bin/python3.10 ../../deps/v8/third_party/inspector_protocol/code_generator.py --jinja_dir ../../deps/v8/third_party --output_base "/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/inspector-generated-output-root/src/inspector" --config ../../deps/v8/src/inspector/inspector_protocol_config.json --inspector_protocol_dir ../../deps/v8/third_party/inspector_protocol
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/lib.host:/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/lib.target:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd ../tools/icu; mkdir -p /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen; cp "/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/icudt71l.dat" "/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/icudt71.dat"
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/lib.host:/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/lib.target:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd ../tools/icu; mkdir -p /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen; "/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/genccode" -e icudt71 -d "/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen" -a gcc -f icudt71_dat "/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/icudt71.dat"
generating assembly code for /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/icudt71.dat
  cc -o /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/icudata/gen/icudt71_dat.o /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/icudt71_dat.S '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-DNODE_OPENSSL_CONF_NAME=nodejs_conf' '-DICU_NO_USER_DATA_OVERRIDE' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DU_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED=' '-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=' '-DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION=1' '-DUCONFIG_NO_SERVICE=1' '-DU_ENABLE_DYLOAD=0' '-DU_HAVE_STD_STRING=1' '-DUCONFIG_NO_BREAK_ITERATION=0' -I../deps/icu-small/source/common  -msign-return-address=all -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-strict-aliasing -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -MMD -MF /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/.deps//home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/icudata/gen/icudt71_dat.o.d.raw   -c
cc: warning: switch ‘-msign-return-address=all’ is no longer supported
  rm -f /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/tools/icu/libicudata.a && ar crsT /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/tools/icu/libicudata.a /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/icudata/gen/icudt71_dat.o
  touch /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/tools/icu/icuuc.stamp
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/lib.host:/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/lib.target:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd ../.; mkdir -p /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen; /usr/bin/python3.10 tools/js2c.py --directory lib --target "/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/node_javascript.cc" config.gypi deps/v8/tools/splaytree.mjs deps/v8/tools/codemap.mjs deps/v8/tools/consarray.mjs deps/v8/tools/csvparser.mjs deps/v8/tools/profile.mjs deps/v8/tools/profile_view.mjs deps/v8/tools/logreader.mjs deps/v8/tools/arguments.mjs deps/v8/tools/tickprocessor.mjs deps/v8/tools/sourcemap.mjs deps/v8/tools/tickprocessor-driver.mjs deps/acorn/acorn/dist/acorn.js deps/acorn/acorn-walk/dist/walk.js deps/cjs-module-lexer/lexer.js deps/cjs-module-lexer/dist/lexer.js deps/undici/undici.js
  touch fb159bb49069b68c85861799aaffe64da95922e4.intermediate
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/lib.host:/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/lib.target:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd ../.; mkdir -p /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/src/node/inspector/protocol; /usr/bin/python3.10 tools/inspector_protocol/code_generator.py --jinja_dir tools/inspector_protocol --output_base "/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/src/" --config src/inspector/node_protocol_config.json
  touch /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/tools/v8_gypfiles/v8_maybe_icu.stamp
  g++ -o /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/gen-regexp-special-case -pthread -rdynamic  -Wl,--start-group /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/gen-regexp-special-case/deps/v8/src/regexp/gen-regexp-special-case.o /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/tools/v8_gypfiles/libv8_libbase.a /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/tools/icu/libicui18n.a /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/tools/icu/libicuucx.a /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/tools/icu/libicudata.a -ldl -lrt -Wl,--end-group
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/lib.host:/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/lib.target:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd ../tools/v8_gypfiles; mkdir -p /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/src/regexp; /usr/bin/python3.10 ../../deps/v8/tools/run.py "/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/gen-regexp-special-case" "/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/src/regexp/special-case.cc"
  touch /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/tools/v8_gypfiles/run_gen-regexp-special-case.stamp
  g++ -o /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/libnode/gen/node_javascript.o /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/node_javascript.cc '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-DNODE_OPENSSL_CONF_NAME=nodejs_conf' '-DICU_NO_USER_DATA_OVERRIDE' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DNODE_ARCH="arm64"' '-DNODE_PLATFORM="linux"' '-DNODE_WANT_INTERNALS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DNODE_OPENSSL_SYSTEM_CERT_PATH=""' '-DHAVE_INSPECTOR=1' '-D__POSIX__' '-DNODE_USE_V8_PLATFORM=1' '-DNODE_HAVE_I18N_SUPPORT=1' '-DHAVE_OPENSSL=1' '-DBASE64_STATIC_DEFINE' '-DUCONFIG_NO_SERVICE=1' '-DU_ENABLE_DYLOAD=0' '-DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION=1' '-DU_HAVE_STD_STRING=1' '-DUCONFIG_NO_BREAK_ITERATION=0' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112' '-DNGHTTP2_STATICLIB' '-DNGTCP2_STATICLIB' '-DNGHTTP3_STATICLIB' -I../src -I/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen -I/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/include -I/home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/src -I../deps/base64/base64/include -I../deps/googletest/include -I../deps/histogram/src -I../deps/uvwasi/include -I../deps/v8/include -I../deps/icu-small/source/i18n -I../deps/icu-small/source/common -I../deps/zlib -I../deps/llhttp/include -I../deps/cares/include -I../deps/uv/include -I../deps/nghttp2/lib/includes -I../deps/brotli/c/include -I../deps/openssl/openssl/include -I../deps/ngtcp2 -I../deps/ngtcp2/ngtcp2/lib/includes -I../deps/ngtcp2/ngtcp2/crypto/includes -I../deps/ngtcp2/ngtcp2/crypto -I../deps/ngtcp2/nghttp3/lib/includes  -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -msign-return-address=all -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror=unused-result -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++14 -MMD -MF /home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/.deps//home/ransike/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/libnode/gen/node_javascript.o.d.raw   -c
g++: warning: switch ‘-msign-return-address=all’ is no longer supported


The warning g++: warning: switch '-msign-return-address=all' is no longer supported obviously tells that the compiler is trying to make use of a non-supported switch. Most of the time, this happens notwithstanding changing compiler versions or options. Now, to fix this, follow these step-by-step methods:

Remove Existing Node.js Version Directories:
Clean up all of the existing directories. These directories may conflict during installation.

rm -rf ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2

rm -rf ~/.nvm/.cache
 
2. Update NVM:
Be at least on the latest version of `nvm` so that there aren't unnecessary issues with the tool itself.

```bash
nvm install-latest-npm
nvm update


Checking and Installing Dependencies:
Make sure the dependencies needed for building Node.js are installed. These must include the likes of build-essential, python3, and gcc/g++.



sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential python3

4. **Set a Compatible GCC/G++ Version:**
The reason behind this error could be the newer version of `gcc/g++`. You can just install a specific, known-to-work-well-with-Node.js-v16 version of `gcc/g++` and set that one.

```bash
sudo apt-get install gcc-10 g++-10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-10 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-10 10


Try to Install Node.js v16 Again:



bash
nvm install v16.20.2

If it still doesn't work, you can manually modify the Node.js source to exclude the unsupported `-msign-return-address=all` switch. Here's how:

1. **Download the Node.js Source:**

bash
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.20.2/node-v16.20.2.tar.gz
tar -xzf node-v16.20.2.tar.gz
cd node-v16.20.2

2. **Remove the Unsupported Switch:**
Look for the `-msign-return-address` switch using `grep` and remove it.
```bash
grep -r 'msign-return-address' .

Edit the files including the provided switch, remove or comment out this line: -msign-return-address=all.

** Node.js Manual Build and Installation:**



./configure
make -j4
sudo make install

4. **Use the installed Node.js version with NVM:**
```bash
nvm use system

After these steps, you should be in a position to install and start using Node.js v16 without the -msign-return-address warning.

Clearing the nvm cache using nvm cache clear, and then removing the existing Node.js version directories using rm -rf ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2 and afterwards, node installation nvm install 16.20.2 worked fine for me. Thanks for the help
